# Android ActionBar disappeared in some of the layouts

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-actionbar, android-manifest

Here is my manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.bankaspace.servicefinder">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher3"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher3_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".doctorSearch" />
            <activity android:name=".garageSearch" />
            <activity android:name=".plumberSearch" />
            <activity android:name=".electricianSearch" />
            <activity android:name=".tutorSearch" />
            <activity android:name=".DetailProfile" />
            <activity android:name=".ContactForm"></activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

here is my layout file

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="#fcfcfc"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/ll">

        <LinearLayout
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
              android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:id="@+id/doctorId"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">
```

I tried to apply a toolbar in place of action bar. In the process I may have changed a bit of lines but I reverted the changes done then, now the action bar is invisible. I have no idea what might cause this, everything is reverted to the original code of lines. Some activities do have the action bar from the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this works for me,
In styles.xml I made a theme that have parent with some of the action bars

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

</style>
```

and then in AndroidManifest.xml for each activity I applied that theme, also with label that is showing the name of the activity, so in your case would be something like

```
<activity
        android:name=".doctorSearch"
        android:label="Doctor Search"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
<activity
        android:name=".garageSearch"
        android:label="Garage Search"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
```

and so on...
, or in styles.xml you can choose some of parents with no action bar, like

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

</style>
```

and just make your own custom tool bar and apply it in layout